# OpenLayers Image WMS not working on IE11

Tags: openlayers

OpenLayers ImageWMS in our website has stopped working for some reason and I assume it's due to IE11 changes/compatibility.

We are pulling from NOAA.gov and showing the weather layer. I created a basic HTML example to show the issue. The image is getting displayed in Edge, Firefox and Chrome without any issues, but no longer working on IE11. Is there a fix for this until IE11 is fully deprecated by Microsoft. Our users still using IE11 on some of their laptops and PCs.

Below is the HTML code based on https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-image.html. Only thing different is the ol.source.ImageWMS section. If you save this snippet in a file and open it in IE11, the image block doesn't show. However it shows up fine in Chrome, Edge and Firefox.

Thank you in advance for your help!

```js
var layers = [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        }),
        new ol.layer.Image({
          extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
          source:   new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                    url: 'https://nowcoast.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/nowcoast/radar_meteo_imagery_nexrad_time/MapServer/export/',
                    params: {dpi: 96,
                    transparent: false,
                    format: 'image/png8' ,
                    f: 'image'
            },
        ratio: 1,
        serverType: 'mapserver'
          })
        })
      ];

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: layers,
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [-10997148, 4569099],
          zoom: 4
        })
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Single Image WMS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wild guess: It might be a problem with the PNG type (as IE had several issues with those). If you can, try other types?

Comment: Hi dube. I have tried jpeg/jpg type and unfortunately it did not work. Thanks!

Comment: I think your code is fine, it's the servers fault. It does not send back a content type header, so the browsers have to guess the content. you either need a proxy or do the requests yourself (which is not fun)